# Execute command if I logged in from a specific user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication, su

I have a server that has a superuser (user1) with special rights to perform certain operations. And there are some other system users.

Is there any way to execute set of commands if and only if I logged in from system user (user2)?

Or any way to identify from which system user I have logged in to my superuser?

For example, I want to run a script which will, if I login from system user (user2), execute:

```
[user2@test ~]$ sudo su - user1
user2 Password:
[user1@test ~]$ sh script.sh
```

Comment: Put the commands in the user's `.profile`, they'll be executed when that user logs in.

Comment: Are you talking about doing something when certain users use `sudo` or `su`?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar i don't what to execute for all the user. only for a specific user

Comment: Each user has their own `.profile` in their home directory.

Comment: but i want to execute script once i logged in my super user, not in system user

Comment: What do you mean by "once I logged in my super user"? Are you talking about using the `su` or `sudo` commands to execute a command as root?

Comment: yes similer like - `[user2@test ~]$ sudo su - user1 \n
user2 Password: \n
[user1@test ~]$ sh script.sh`

Comment: You should put those details in the question.

Comment: @Barmar i have modified the question and is there any way to get this kind of automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `who am i` command will show the name of the user that originally logged in on that terminal. You can use that to detect if you've switched from one user account to another with `su`. So in `~user1/.profile` you can put:

```
orig_user=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
if [[ $orig_user = user2 ]]
then
    sh script.sh
fi
```

Comment: Is there any way, instead of username i can use UID?

Comment: I don't think so. The original uid isn't saved anywhere.